# ng-if not updating DOM on variable change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

I am adding a loading_gif to my google maps and using google.maps.event.addListener() to determine when the map is done loading and update a variable to stop the loading spinner.  It looks like everything is working as intended and I am seeing the variable get updated but the spinner still displays.

My loading spinner:

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:99;top:85px;left:38%;" ng-if="mapLoader==0">
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    LOADING MAP...
    <br><img style="height:100px;" ng-src="img/ajax_loading.gif">
  </p>
</div>
```

The app starts, the loading starts, the map loads in the background but the spinner never goes away.  In console, I see all the console messages printing out - including the one that indicates the map has finished loading and setting the `$scope.mapLoader = 1` which should stop the DIV with the loading gif to hide....but it doesn't

My controller:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope,$ionicModal,$ionicPopover,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$rootScope,$state,constants,apiService) {

  $scope.mapLoader = 0 ;
  $scope.mapTrigger = 0 ;

  // recursive function to test for maps finished loading
  //setMap is a global variable set elsewhere.
  function checkLoader() {
    console.log("CHECKING LOADER") ;
    if ($scope.mapLoader == 0) {
      if (setMap && $scope.mapTrigger == 0) {
        $scope.mapTrigger = 1 ;
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(setMap,'tilesloaded', (function() {
          console.log("\tMAP LOADED") ; // These two successfully print out
          $scope.mapLoader = 1 ;        // this should stop the DIV from displaying.
          console.log($scope.mapLoader) ; // These two successfully print out
        })) ; 
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("\tChecking Map") ;
        checkLoader() ;                // repeat function again
      },500) ;                         // 1/2 second intervals
    } 
  }

  if ($scope.mapLoader == 0) {
    checkLoader() ;
  } else {
    $scope.mapLoader = 1 ;
  }
})
```

Printed out to console:

```
CHECKING LOADER
    Checking Map
CHECKING LOADER
    Checking Map
CHECKING LOADER
    Checking Map
CHECKING LOADER
    MAP LOADED
    1
Checking Map
CHECKING LOADER
```

Comment: I even changed the `ng-if="mapLoader==0"` to `ng-show="mapLoader==0"` and it still isn't working.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like so

```
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(setMap,'tilesloaded', (function() {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
           $scope.mapLoader = 1;
       });
   })) ;
```

You have to tell AngularJS that you have some events, that are not tracked by Angular, and you need to apply changes that were done in a moment.

Read more for `$apply` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide:-When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) and [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html).

Comment: thanks.  That did the trick.  Now I need to read up on why...thanks for the links to, gonna read up on it now.